# Terminator doesn't render layout correctly

Tags: command-line, terminator

I've created a custom layout. But when I start it with the command `terminator -l 3col` it will scamp all columns/rows together. Screenshot pretty much says it all.
[image]
*yes I know, They are rows not columns*

What is going wrong?
Running Ubuntu with Cinnamon desktop

**~/.config/terminator/config contents**

```
[global_config]
  broadcast_default = off
  suppress_multiple_term_dialog = True
[keybindings]
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child1]]]
      directory = ""
      parent = window0
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
    [[[window0]]]
      parent = ""
      type = Window
  [[3col]]
    [[[child0]]]
      fullscreen = False
      last_active_term = 3a430792-9a19-4b87-b4b1-7af7fd4c48b8
      last_active_window = True
      maximised = False
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      size = 1028, 692
      title = ~ - Terminal
      type = Window
    [[[child1]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child0
      position = 216
      ratio = 0.312138728324
      type = VPaned
    [[[child3]]]
      order = 1
      parent = child1
      position = 226
      ratio = 0.475789473684
      type = VPaned
    [[[terminal2]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child1
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      uuid = d0309320-b5d4-4731-93bb-9b40d24f0fd2
    [[[terminal4]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child3
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      uuid = 3a430792-9a19-4b87-b4b1-7af7fd4c48b8
    [[[terminal5]]]
      order = 1
      parent = child3
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      uuid = 3ebceeda-52d1-4796-8415-c7fd5f02d756
[plugins]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    background_darkness = 0.8
    background_type = transparent
    cursor_color = "#aaaaaa"
```

Answer (score 0):

(In case someone is still looking for an answer)

Maybe you're using the version 1.90 which is known to have problems when rendering layouts.

After installing 1.91 I've successfully setup the default layout without problems, I've made a document describing this and [how to setup the default layout properly](http://migueleonardortiz.com.ar/linux/setup-terminator-default-layout-with-custom-commands/1546).